# Getting "pax archive volume change required" prompt during build configuration

Tags: build, buildconfiguration, pax

I am trying to build [fastjet-3.0.1](http://fastjet.fr/all-releases.html) on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

On running the following:

```
./configure --enable-allcxxplugins
```

I get the following message:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... 
ATTENTION! pax archive volume change required.
Ready for archive volume: 1
Input archive name or "." to quit pax.
Archive name >
```

I tried looking up what Pax is and what to do with this error, but did not find anything useful. Any help on this will be great
! Thanks.

Comment: Personally I think this is a defect in automake/autoconf, but I don't think they see it that way.  For example, this [guy](http://tinyurl.com/z8elmc6) ran into the same issue, but the response was basically "I don't think there is much that can be done about this in Automake".  There is something they can do, however, to make pax not require interactive input: [add the -O flag](http://tinyurl.com/zup635e).

Comment: @JWPeterson this definitely is a bug in the software that is spread under the name "automake". A test that calls `tar` with options that are definitely inapropriate to `tar` is broken. A test that is not prepared to deal with the idiosyncratic behavior of mirbsd pax should be fixed. A test that in 2020  tries to enforce an archive format from 1988 should be revised. People who expect to only see GNU software on a computer cannot think outside the box.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to JW Peterson's comment, I could circumvent this problem with a wrapper to `pax(1)`:

`~/local/mypax/pax`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/pax -O "$@"
```

This has to come earlier than the underlying `pax(1)` command in the `$PATH` environment variable:

```sh
export PATH=$HOME/local/mypax:$PATH
```

Comment: Does this has the same effect as entering `.` at the interactive prompt?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure. Man page might have the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, and I solved it by run "sudo ./configure".

Comment: In what sense does this solve the problem? What happened differently as the root user?